# how can i use a variable in this SelectSingleNode statement

Tags: c#, xml, selectsinglenode

how can i use a variable in this SelectSingleNode statement

```
   oldCd = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[id={0}]",id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `id` is an attribute of `student` element

```
root.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//students/student[@id='{0}']",id))
```

if it is sub element

```
root.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//students/student[id[text()='{0}']]",id))
```

Comment: knowing that "id" is a string converted to an int32 should that be a problem, i used your second line of code since its a sub child but i keep getting an error from this exact line that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " do you know what this means??

Comment: @HammamMuhareb: Are you sure that `root` isn't `null`? Post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem if you're still having issues.

Comment: @HammamMuhareb XML is case sensitive. Is it possible that your xml contains `Students` not `students`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* use `string.Format` to create the XPath expression, as shown in L.B's answer.

Personally I wouldn't though - I'd use LINQ to XML, which doesn't mix code and data as much as using XPath. It smacks of the same problem as the normal source of SQL injection attacks.

The LINQ to XML query would be like this:

```
var node = doc.Root.Elements("Students")
                   .Elements("Student")
                   .Where(x => (string) x.Element("id") == id)
                   .SingleOrDefault();
```

(If `id` is an `int`, you could cast the `XElement` to `int` instead of `string`.)

I generally prefer querying with LINQ to XML over using XPath; others have different preferences, of course.

Comment: Is there an advantage to casting the XElement (assuming that x is an XElement) to a string rather than accessing it's .Value property?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: It means that if the element doesn't exist, you end up with `null` instead of an exception; in other words, this query will just skip `Student` elements without a nested `id` element. Whether that's desirable or not depends on the context.